# Primefaces: dialog doesn't show up when dataTable is used

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

```
 <ui:define name ="content">
    <div align="right" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <p:commandButton onclick="PF('userCreateDialog').show();" value="+ Admin"  style="align-items:right;"></p:commandButton>
    </div>
    <h:form id="userForm">


        <p:dialog header="Create User" id="userCreateDialog" widgetVar="userCreateDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="true">
            <p:outputPanel id="userDataCreate">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: " />
                    <p:inputText id="username" value="#{userAddController.user.username}"/>
                    <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: " />
                    <p:password id="password" value="#{userAddController.user.password}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:separator />
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{userAddController.doSaveUser()}" oncomplete="PF('userCreateDialog').hide()" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Abort" onclick="PF('userCreateDialog').hide()"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

So far the dialog shows up when I click on the "+ Admin" `<p:commandButton>`, but when I insert a `<p:dataTable>` within the `<h:form>` "userForm" the table and the button will be rendered, but the dialog doesn't show up anymore.

When I insert a `<p:outputLabel>` within `<h:form>` instead the `<p:dataTable>` everything works fine.

I tried to rebuild my file step-by-step to see where the mistake is and it just can be the `<p:dataTable>`, but WHY?

Hope anyone has a tip for me.

Comment: What happens if you put another h:form inside the dialog and appendTo="@(body)" on the dialog? Did you check both server log and browser console for errors? Also, a commandButton must be inside a form